# How to get different controllers to use different configurations of $httpProvider in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-controller, angularjs-http

I have a AngularJS project using the directory layout from angular-seed.
https://github.com/angular/angular-seed

app.js contains the configuration of my http provider. All my controllers have to use the same configuration of the http provider in app.js .

In app.js,

```
angular.module('myApp', [
  'ngRoute',
  'myApp.filters',
  'myApp.services',
  'myApp.directives',  
  'myApp.controllers',
]).
config(['$httpProvider', function($httpProvider)
{
    if (!$httpProvider.defaults.headers.get) {
        $httpProvider.defaults.headers.get = {};    
    }

    //disable IE ajax request caching
    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.get['If-Modified-Since'] = '0'; 
}
```

I have a controller XXXCtrl which works when app.js is as above. I have another controller YYYCtrl which does not work unless I comment away the code inside `config(['$httpProvider', function($httpProvider)`.

So, my problem is this. How to get different controllers to use different configurations of $httpProvider in AngularJS? Can $httpProvider be configured inside individual controllers?

Comment: I don't believe there is any other way around that than declaring your controllers in different modules.

Comment: Can I configure $httpProvider inside individual controllers?

Comment: @ivarni: Do you mean creating another app.js with a new declaration of angular.module?

Comment: @user3293156 NO, but you can override default headers. All angular services are singletons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can override $http headers per call

```
$http.get(url, {headers:{...}});
```

Since services are singletons, they are configured once and for all.You can have multiple module.config functions but it wouldnt help.

You could also use [Interceptors](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24http) to configure http requests.

Comment: Thanks! You saved me plenty of time. I was about to create multiple module.config functions.